# Path edits are not persisted after shell is restarted in Ubuntu WSL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, path

I just installed miniconda3 on Ubuntu (through wsl on Windows 10).

If I try to execute `conda --version`, I get an error saying that conda is not a recognized command. To solve this, I ran export `PATH=/miniconda3/bin:$PATH` which worked as expected. However, if I close and re-open the Ubuntu terminal and try to run `conda --version` again I get the `conda is not a recognized command` again. It appears that the path variable is not persisted.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

#### It appears that the path variable is not persisted. How can I solve this?

You need to add the `export` command to the appropriate `bash` start up file.

That is usually one of `~/.profile`, or `~/.bash_profile`.

See [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/).

---

#### Further Reading:

- [How to set your $PATH variable in Linux | Opensource.com](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/set-path-linux)
- [bash - How to correctly add a path to PATH? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)